# Is there any way to make aside element height equal to main element height?

Tags: html, css

Here is the issue I am having: My main element has a pretty long height due to the content inside it. However, my aside element (sidebar) has far less content and so is shorter, which is not aesthetically pleasing.

How can I make the aside element height equal to the main element height (possibly in all situations when I will have more content in the main element)?

Here is my main element:

```
main {
        display: block;
        width: 75%; 
        float: left;
    }
```

Here is my aside element:

```
aside {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 21%;
    float: right;
    padding: 2%;    
}
```

Setting a specific height for the aside element did not work: when I add content to the main element the aside element height properties become obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a wrapping div, use `display: flex;`

```css
.wrap{
  display: flex;
 width: 100%;
}
.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
    width: 75%;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.aside {
  border: 1px solid blue;
display: block;
background-color: #fff;
width: 21%;
float: right;
padding: 2%;    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="main">
Main
  </div>
  <div class="aside">
Aside
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The solution you gave seems to work out, I will try it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("load", resizeAside);
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeAside);

function resizeAside(){
   var mainHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].height;
   document.getElementsByTagName('aside')[0].height = mainHeight;
}
```

Comment: Do not know JS yet, will try when I will learn it, thanks a lot!